# ¿Cómo filtro con Awk las líneas que cumplen dos condiciones determinadas?

Tags: shell, shell-script, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un archivo CSV sobre la tasa de suicidios en un rango de años determinado. Estoy realizando un script de awk que al pasarle el nombre del país y el año me devuelva las líneas que tengan dichos parámetros. Sin embargo, estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de hacerlo.

El fichero que tengo tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
country,year,sex,age,suicides_no,population,suicides/100k pop,country-year,HDI for year, gdp_for_year ($) ,gdp_per_capita ($),generation
Albania,1987,male,15-24 years,21,312900,6.71,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
Albania,1987,male,35-54 years,16,308000,5.19,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Silent
Albania,1987,female,15-24 years,14,289700,4.83,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
Albania,1987,male,75+ years,1,21800,4.59,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
Albania,1987,male,25-34 years,9,274300,3.28,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Boomers
Albania,1987,female,75+ years,1,35600,2.81,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
Albania,1987,female,35-54 years,6,278800,2.15,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Silent
Albania,1987,female,25-34 years,4,257200,1.56,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Boomers
Albania,1987,male,55-74 years,1,137500,0.73,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
```

Esas son los 10 primeros registros que tiene el fichero. Pues bien, el script awk que he realizado es tal que:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    FS=","
    RS="\n"
}
$0 ~ country
$0 ~ year
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutar el script, por ejemplo, como `./script.awk country=Albania year=2001 fichero`, la salida que obtengo es la de todos los registros de Albania, independientemente del año, y la del resto de los países en el año 2001, cuando yo lo que querría es solo obtener los registros de Albania en 2001.

¿Alguien sabe en qué parte del script estoy cometiendo un error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un CSV y por tanto `FS` debe ser la coma. El separador de registros es el salto de línea, por lo que `RS` no hace falta tocarlo por ser el valor por defecto.

Así pues, la solución que desearíamos es del tipo:

```
awk -F, -v country="Albania" -v year=1988 '$1 == country && $2 == year' fichero
```

Si lo movemos a un fichero, sería del tipo:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    FS=","
}
$1 == country && $2 == year
```

Nótese que en tu caso funciona el decirle `$0 ~ country year` pues de alguna forma estás juntando el campo 1 y el 2 y le pides que la línea entera sea parecida a la unión de "country" y "year". En concreto, que empiecen igual. Ahora bien, esto es algo débil pues si le pasaras un año "19" seguramente te valdría todo aquello que sea del tipo 19XX. Por tanto, si quieres usar un filtro exacto vale más la pena comprobar campo a campo y decir `country == $1` y `year == $2`.

Comment: Genial fedorqui, siempre estás súper atento! Muchas gracias por la respuesta!!

Comment: Es que las preguntas de Awk son un vicio :D

Answer (score 0):

Vale, era tan sencillo como poner las variables country y year en la misma lína:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    FS=","
    RS="\n"
}
$0 ~ country year
```

Disculpen las molestias!!